# Spark classpath in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

For Spark jobs running on YARN (yarn-client), is it possible to specify the classpath with jars located in HDFS

A bit like it was possible with Map Reduce jobs with :

```
DistributedCache.addFileToClassPath(Path file, Configuration conf, FileSystem fs)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the SparkContext documentation:

> def **addJar**(path: String):
> Unit
>
> Adds a JAR dependency for all tasks to
> be executed on this SparkContext in the future. The path passed can be
> either a local file, a file in HDFS (or other Hadoop-supported
> filesystems), an HTTP, HTTPS or FTP URI, or local:/path for a file on
> every worker node.

So I think it is enough to just add this in your sparkContext initialization:

```
sc.addJar("hdfs://your/path/to/whatever.jar")
```

If you want to add just a file, there is a relevant `addFile()` method.

See [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext) for more.