# Running spark application from HDInsight cluster headnode

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-hdinsight, azure-data-factory, apache-spark-2.0

I am trying to run spark scala application from head node of azure HDInsight cluster with command

> spark-submit --class com.test.spark.Wordcount  SparkJob1.jar 
>   wasbs://*containername*@<*storageaccountname*>/sample.sas7bdat
>   wasbs://*containername*@<*storageaccountname*>/sample.csv

I am getting below exception with it.

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of
>   scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of
>   type scala.collection.Seq in instance of
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD

Same jar file is working if I invoke from Azure data factory . Am I missing some configuration with spark-submit command?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, it was caused by your code logic about type conversion. There is a similar SO thread [How to fix java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List to field type scala.collection.Seq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953245/how-to-fix-java-lang-classcastexception-cannot-assign-instance-of-scala-collect) which had been answered, I think you can refer to it and check your code for resolving the issue.